# How to use data-filter inside div

Tags: html, css

The following code works.

```
<ul><li>
  <a href="#" data-filter=".design">
    <h3>Render Plan</h3>
  </a>
</li></ul>

<div class="design col-md-3">
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/01_RenderPlan/Big Size Images/Turiya_FloorPlan_Big_01.jpg"><img src="images/01_RenderPlan/Thumbnail Images/Turiya_FloorPlan_Small_01.jpg" class="web"></a>
</div>
```

But when i try to put it inside another div it fails to filter the data.
Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="design col-md-3">
        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/01_RenderPlan/Big Size Images/Turiya_FloorPlan_Big_01.jpg"><img src="images/01_RenderPlan/Thumbnail Images/Turiya_FloorPlan_Small_01.jpg" class="web"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help how to filter data inside that div. Thank you

Comment: That doesn't seem to be plain HTML. Could you add tags for other frameworks you are using?

Comment: Can you please provide jsfiddle version, or what type data-filter you using jQuery or else?